# Google Maps API - questions on hover / URL click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get a Google Maps instance setup, where I can have the marker icons change into a larger image on hover.  I am loading the larger image within arrays and then trying to pass those values into the callback event function.  For some reason I only get a default map marker showing on hover, and not the image.

You can see where I am doing this below by using the "testVar".

https://jsfiddle.net/sj1zv02a/

```
for (i = 0; i < locations_programs.length; i++) {
    var id = 'programs' + i;

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_programs[i][1], locations_programs[i][2]),
        map: map,
        id: id,
        icon: 'http://www.christielakekids.com/_images/new/blue_circle.png',
        url: locations_programs[i][5],
        image: locations_programs[i][4],
        zIndex: 100
    });

    var testVar = locations_programs[i][4];


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (event, testVar) {
        this.setIcon(testVar);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function (event) {
        this.setIcon('http://www.christielakekids.com/_images/new/blue_circle.png');
    });
```

I would also like to know how to attach a URL to the larger image so it will redirect there when clicked.  I have the "URL" parameter set in the marker code, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Hi user1110562 I have posted an aswer to your question, I.sorry for the fast final indication in addlistener call in your previous question. But anyway i hope the answer could be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  have found this solution  (the sample is for //**** PROGRAMS only but is easly extendible for the other section.
the [JSFiddle for test](https://jsfiddle.net/b0j0vfza/)

And the code for a better explanation

In the marker attributes add a `altIcon` attribute and assign to this the image you need. 
In mouseover listener set the icon using `this.setIcon(this.altIcon)`

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_programs[i][1], locations_programs[i][2]),
   map: map
  ,id: id
  ,icon: 'http://www.christielakekids.com/_images/new/blue_circle.png'
  ,url: locations_programs[i][5]
  ,image: locations_programs[i][4]
  ,zIndex:100
  ,altIcon: locations_programs[i][4]
});



  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(event) {
      this.setIcon(this.altIcon);
  });
```

I met some difficulties to display images in the array. (the site says file not found) so inside jsfiddle I used icons with different colors.

Comment: Thanks very much.  This is working now.  I think I may have had it working prior to this, but didn't realize I was using the wrong path to the images!

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the URL to work when you click on the larger image?

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        window.location.href = this.url;
      });